# Why is the winding number defined as $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz$?

Tags: complex-analysis, winding-number

I'd appreciate some clear explanation as to why the number is defined as such. I think in my book, in the proof of the *argument principle*, it seems like this integral pops out of the blue, without providing motivation. In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number#Complex_analysis), I think they are using a special case, and also without much motivation for this division of $\frac{dz}{z}$.

Comment: The winding number (of $C$ with respect to $z=0$) is defined as $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{1}{z}dz$, and that is the variation of $\arg z$ along $C$. Your integral is the winding number of $f \circ C$ .

Comment: the argument principle just says that (with $\gamma(t)$ your parametrized contour) $\frac{f'(\gamma(t))}{f(\gamma(t))}\gamma'(t)$ is the derivative of $L(t) = \log(f(\gamma(t))) + 2 i \pi k(t)$ where $k(t)$ is piecewise constant and integer valued, counting the number of zeros/poles inside the contour with multiplicity and weighted by the winding number

Comment: @MartinR how is it so that the variation of $\arg z$ along $C$ has something to do with $\frac{1}{z}$? That's the part I don't get.

Comment: @sequence: But that is explained in the Wikipedia section that you linked to.

Comment: @MartinR I guess that's to explicitly derive the differential $d\theta$?

Answer (score 0):

The anti-derivative of $\frac{1}{z}$ is the logarithm. Thus, we can view $\int_C\frac{1}{z}$ as measuring the difference in the logarithm of the curve $C$ at its starting point before and after completing the circuit. Writing this point as $re^{i\theta}$ we see that the imaginary part of the logarithm will measure something to do with the angle of the function. Because the angle of the curve varies continuously, it must pickup an additional $2\pi$ radians every time it returns to its starting point, or more generally winds about the origin. Taking the difference of the logarithm evaluated at the beginning and end of this path exactly tracks this difference in angle.

Comment: Why does the logarithm have to be involved?

Comment: We can check that the derivative of $\log z$ is just $\frac{1}{z}$ (in a region small enough so that $\log z$ is single valued). This follows from the definition of the logarithm as the inverse of the exponential map with the formula for the derivative of the inverse.

Comment: Right, but I still don't see conceptually how the fact that $\log(z)$ is the inverse of the exponential function is relevant to the winding number.